# How to embed video like Firefox page?

Tags: video, html, firefox3.5

I just updated Firefox 3.5.
When I visited [Firefox website](http://en-gb.www.mozilla.com/en-GB/firefox/3.5/whatsnew/) there is a video. When you click it, it enlarges and plays. I wonder if anyone knows how you can do it. Does it use any plug-in?

Comment: The whole point of HTML5 videos is that it doesn't use any plugins or extensions or anything not out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox):

> Firefox 3.5 introduced support for the
>   HTML 5 audio and video elements,
>   offering the ability to easily embed
>   media into HTML documents.  Currently,
>   Ogg Theora, Ogg Vorbis, and WAV format
>   media is supported.

You can embed video in the same way like this:

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" autoplay>  
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.  
</video>
```

Note however that currently only Firefox 3.5 supports following tag and only with Ogg Theora/Vorbis content. Other browsers will get only: *Your browser does not support the `video` element.*.

Moreover Firefox 3.5 doesn't handle incorrect videos very well. If the video is not in supported format, it will just display blank area. I suggest reading more on the issues and workarounds at the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox)

No one really knows how will standardization of `<video>` tag go, but let's cross our fingers.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the new [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_5) element `<video>`

It provides new elements like `<video>` or `<audio>`. The idea is to make obsolete some extra plugin required.

For the moment, HTML5 is not normalized (it will not be for another 5 to 10 years)

Answer (score 0):

just look at page source it just JavaScript and video form dailymotion.com :)

Answer (score -1):

The thing you want to do can be done using jQuery. You can find more about jQuery at [www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)